# Getting equally distributed, certain amount of values from matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

If we have an axis and we want to place fewer ticks, we can do that like so

```
axes( ... 'XTick', x(1:5:end) ...);
```

The problem I have is: How can we get say three elements of equal distant indices one from each other from a matrix, **independently of it's size**? What would be a easy and short way of doing this?

```
x1 = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
x2 = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];

x1(get3)
x2(get3)

>> 1 3 5
>> 1 4 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
>> x2 = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];
>> n = 3; %// assumed to divide the number of elements of x2
>> x2(1:numel(x2)/n:end)
ans =
     1     4     7
```